# Android FolioReader decrypt HTML content

Tags: android, android-library, epub

I am using [Folioreader](https://github.com/FolioReader/FolioReader-Android) in my app to show epubs. Epub file's HTML content is encrypted(only the HTML files). I want to decrypt the HTML file content. There is a class called HtmlTask.It is an AsyncTask.

```
public class HtmlTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

private static final String TAG = "HtmlTask";

private HtmlTaskCallback callback;

public HtmlTask(HtmlTaskCallback callback) {
    this.callback = callback;
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
    String strUrl = urls[0];
    try {
        URL url = new URL(strUrl);
        URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
        InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, AppUtil.charsetNameForURLConnection(urlConnection)));
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            stringBuilder.append(line).append('\n');
        }
        if (stringBuilder.length() > 0)
            stringBuilder.deleteCharAt(stringBuilder.length() - 1);
        Log.e(TAG, "htm content");
        String data = stringBuilder.toString();
        Log.d(TAG, data);
        return data;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "HtmlTask failed", e);
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String htmlString) {
    if (htmlString != null) {
        callback.onReceiveHtml(htmlString);
    } else {
        callback.onError();
    }
    cancel(true);
}
```

}

data variable do not receive the encrypted content in HTML files. As I understood I need to decrypt the HTML file's data before this async task. how can I decrypt and serve the HTML content? I need to add a callback for decrypt the html content . How can I achieve this

Comment: folioreader library uses R2-streamer library